# Convert points from one image plane to another plane using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am trying to calibrate a camera so I can take an arbitrary point on the camera image and transform it to be on another 2D plane (the floor of a room), so I can accurately figure out where an object is on the floor relative to other points on the floor.

So far, I've looked at several different approaches using OpenCV, but it is not clear to me which is the best approach..

1. Compute the fundamental matrix, correlating points on the two planes. This approach seems simple, but I'm not sure how to do a transformation of a point once I have the fundamental matrix.
2. Use a homographic transform. Also seems like a possibility for correlating points on two planes with a different perspective
3. Compute the perspective transform
4. Find extrinsic camera parameters (seems like this approach may require more information than I have available to me)

What is the correct approach here? It seems like a pretty common problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a homographic transform, if you provide 4 well spaced points the transform produced by findHomography will be well suited to your needs. Then you can apply the transformation using perspectiveTransform.